# How to set date range when using d3.time.scale()

Tags: d3.js

My aim is pretty simple, I would like to create a timeline using dates from a CSV. I would then like to plot circles at different points along this timeline.

[Full code](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2UuPZnoCJYzfUjdLWIx?p=info)

**data**

```
,,Name,First names,s,r,Nat,born,starting point,starting date,arrival date,days,km,Assist,Support,Style,note,
1,1,KAGGE,Erling,,,Nor,1/15/1963,Berkner Island,11/18/1992,1/7/1993,50,appr. 1300,n,n,solo,first solo unassisted,
2,2,ARNESEN,Liv,f,,Nor,6/1/1953,Hercules Inlet,11/4/1994,12/24/1994,50,1130,n,n,solo,first woman unassisted,
```

The dates I would like to use are ['starting point']

I think the problem is here: I'm unsure what the domain should look like (and how to find min and max)

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain(['11/18/1992', '10/25/2013']).range([0, w]);
```

I am attempting to plot the circles using cx

```
.attr('cx', function(d) {
      return x(d['starting date'])
    })
```

**code**

```
 d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

  var cd = data.filter(function(d) {
    return (d.Style == "solo")
  });

  var de = cd.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.days - b.days
  })

  console.log(de)

  var h = 400;
  var w = 500;

  var x = d3.time.scale().domain(['11/18/1992', '10/25/2013']).range([0, w]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(10)

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("g")

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.selectAll('.start')
    .data(de)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return x(d['starting date'])
    })
    .attr('cy', 10)
    .attr('r', 5)
    .style('fill', 'red')

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how d3 will coerce your date strings into dates so I'd suggest converting them explicitly. I think that should fix your problem.

First in the source data e.g.

```
  var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
  var cd = data.filter(function(d) {
    return (d.Style == "solo")
  })
  .map(function(d){
    d["starting date"] = timeFormat.parse(d["starting date"]);
    d["arrival date"] = timeFormat.parse(d["arrival date"]);
    return d;
  });
```

And then similarly when you create your domain...

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([timeFormat.parse('11/18/1992'), timeFormat.parse('10/25/2013')])
  .range([0, w]);
```

To determine the extent of the dates automatically you could use `d3.array.extent` ([docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent))